# Parse url from another site using PHP

Tags: php, html-table

I have a webpage with a small table, for example:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="123">
                <div class="box-title title collapsed-box">
                    <a class="title" href="URL" target="_top" title="TITLE" data-original-click-url="URL">
                        <span>TEXT</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

in this table there is link, which is changing every several minutes (doesn't matter time).

How can I fully copy URL without cutting anything?

*P.S. I don't know PHP so it will be great if you'll explain to me with examples*

Comment: Are you able to load the source code of that website into a string variable in PHP?

Comment: SO isn't a free coding service, please try yourself and come back if you run into problems

Comment: If you don't know PHP then why are you using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You cat parse URL with regexp

> |click-url\=\"(.*)\">|

```
$string = '<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="123">
<div class="box-title title collapsed-box">
<a class="title" href="URL" target="_top" title="TITLE" data-original-click-url="URL"><span>TEXT</span></a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>';

preg_match_all('|click\-url\=\"(.*)\">|', $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Example: http://ideone.com/KJg8y2

Your result in $matches[1][0]

Comment: `<?php`
`$url="URL of another website";`
`$ch = curl_init($url);`

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'IE20');`
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);`
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, '1');`

`$text = curl_exec($ch);`

`curl_close($ch);`

`$table = "/<table>(.*)<\/table>/siU";`
`preg_match($table, $text, $data);`

`echo $data[1];`
`?>`


I'm trying to do this with this code but URL is cutted
for example another webpages name is google.com/sport/abg.php

when I parse by this code at my website
I get result as

mywebsite.com/abg.php

google.com and directory /sport/ is gone

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

the above is to echo the url.. try this...